# For loop only runs once c++

Tags: c++, loops

Hi im trying to run the drunk walk problem which is similar to flipping a coin. I have the code written but it only enters the for loop once instead of 1,000,000 times like I want it to. I cant see what I did wrong so I hope you all can point me in the right direction, Thank you.

```
  cout << "enter the starting position.\n";
  cin >> i;
  cout << "At starting block " << i << endl;

  for(j = 1; j < 1000000; j++)
  {

     while(i < 8 && i > 1)
     {
        x = rand() % 3;
        if(x == 0)
        {
           i++;
           tot_mov++;
        }
        else
        {
           i--;
           tot_mov++;
        }
     }

    if(i == 1)
    {
       tot_pub++;
    }

    if(i == 8)
    {
       tot_hom++;
    }

  }

    avg_mov = tot_mov / 1000000;
    avg_pub = tot_pub / 1000000;
    avg_hom = tot_hom / 1000000;

    cout << "Total moves " << tot_mov << endl;
    cout << "Average moves " << avg_mov << endl;
    cout << "Total Home " << tot_hom << endl;
    cout << "Average home " << avg_hom << endl;
    cout << "Total pub " << tot_pub << endl;
    cout << "Average pub " << avg_pub << endl;

    return;
```

Comment: What is the type of `j`?

Comment: What is the type of `tot_mov`, `tot_pub` and `tot_hom`? If int, your values  are rounded down to a nearest integers in the divisions.

Comment: How do you know that it runs only once?

Comment: The loop is not run once... So why do you think that?

Comment: Looks like it runs the correct number of times, but your inner while loop will only run once, since you are not resetting i before it runs the second time, guaranteeing that i is outside of the range of the while condition.

Answer (score 1):

The issue, as @MattJordan said in the comments, is that you don't reset `i` during your loop, and don't use a temporary variable.  The loop itself is running all 1,000,000 times, it just isn't *doing* anything once `i` no longer meets the `while` loop's condition.

(Also, it was only looping 999,999 times, since you initialised `j` to `1` instead of `0`.)

Try this:

```
cout << "enter the starting position.\n";
cin >> i;
cout << "At starting block " << i << endl;

for(int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
{
    int i_temp = i;

    while(i_temp < 8 && i_temp > 1)
    {
        x = rand() % 3;
        if(x == 0)
        {
            i_temp++;
            tot_mov++;
        }
        else
        {
            i_temp--;
            tot_mov++;
        }
    }

    if(i_temp == 1)
    {
        tot_pub++;
    }

    if(i_temp == 8)
    {
        tot_hom++;
    }

}

// Casts are optional, they're there to prevent
//  any integer truncation before value is saved to
//  the double.
avg_mov = static_cast<double>(tot_mov) / 1000000;
avg_pub = static_cast<double>(tot_pub) / 1000000;
avg_hom = static_cast<double>(tot_hom) / 1000000;

cout << "Total moves " << tot_mov << endl;
cout << "Average moves " << avg_mov << endl;
cout << "Total Home " << tot_hom << endl;
cout << "Average home " << avg_hom << endl;
cout << "Total pub " << tot_pub << endl;
cout << "Average pub " << avg_pub << endl;

return;
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/HzmFlY).

Comment: @l.sch You're welcome.  Might I suggest thanking Matt Jordan in the above comments, too?  He's the one that pointed it out, I just changed the code to implement it.